# ET.find() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, elementtree, xml.etree

I'm newbie in Python and getting the error

> ET.find() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

during the execution of

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = {'conv_svc': 'http://schemas.com/serviceconvert'}            
jobTypesXml = self.__server_request(url, None)    
root = ET.fromstring(jobTypesXml)    
for job in root.find('conv_svc:GetJobTypesResult', ns):
```

My first question is: what type is deduced in the following initialization?

```
ns = {'conv_svc': 'http://schemas.com/serviceconvert'}
```

Answering this I can go further to find out the error by myself! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `find()` method [only takes a single argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) so you cannot do whatever it is you're attempting (at least not with `find()`).

To answer your question, `{'conv_svc': 'http://schemas.com/serviceconvert'}` is a dictionary and would be interpreted as a single argument. If you are wondering about why the error states that you're passing 3 arguments (which you're not), it's because `self` is also counted as an argument to class methods.

```
class Testing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2

    def do_something(self, b):
        self.a += b

obj = Testing()
obj.do_something(2, 3) # Clearly passing only 2 arguments
```

Gives:

```
TypeError: do_something() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @ShreyashSSarnayak for pointing out that `find()` can take [an optional extra argument *in Python 3*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find). The error message confirms that you are using Python 2, but perhaps reading some documentation associated with Python 3.

Comment: In python3 it takes [two arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find)

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak Aha, so the error is that they're using Python 2 and using Python 3 documentation (the error posted in the question proves that they can't pass the optional argument). I will edit, thanks.